# Navigate from one app to another using Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I need to Navigate from one app to another in Xamarin.Forms.

Tried this but didn't work

await Xamarin.Essentials.Launcher.OpenAsync("myapp://com.companyname.myapp1");

Comment: is that custom url scheme registered on the device?

Comment: I tried to register it in the manifest but it is showing error.But after adding IntentFilter in mainactivity it is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose the package name of the app you want to open is `com.xamarin.secondapp`.

Then you need to add `IntentFilter` and `Exported =true` to `MainActivity.cs` of the app you want to open(`com.xamarin.secondapp`).

Just as follows.

```
    [Activity(Label = "SearchBarDemos", Icon = "@mipmap/icon", Theme = "@style/MainTheme", MainLauncher = true,Exported =true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)] 
    [
    IntentFilter
    (
        new[] { Android.Content.Intent.ActionView },
        Categories = new[]
            {
                Android.Content.Intent.CategoryDefault,
                Android.Content.Intent.CategoryBrowsable
            },
        DataSchemes = new[] { "myapp" }
    )
]
    public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            LoadApplication(new App());
        }
    }
```

Note: remember to add code `DataSchemes = new[] { "myapp" }`.

For the current app, you need to add `queries` tag for the app you want to open in file `manifest.xml`.

For example:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" package="com.companyname.openappapp1">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21" android:targetSdkVersion="33" />
    <application android:label="OpenappApp1.Android" android:theme="@style/MainTheme">

      </application>
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />


      <queries>
            <package android:name="com.xamarin.secondapp" />
      </queries>
</manifest>
```

And the code is:

```
    private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        OpenSecondApp();
    }

    public async void OpenSecondApp()
    {

        var supportsUri = await Launcher.CanOpenAsync("myapp://");
        if (supportsUri)
            await Launcher.OpenAsync("myapp://com.xamarin.secondapp");

    }
```

Comment: Suppose I need to open any other app like google chrome/Youtube so how it can possible?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public class Test
{
    public async Task OpenRideShareAsync()
    {
        var supportsUri = await Launcher.CanOpenAsync("myapp://");
        if (supportsUri)
            await Launcher.OpenAsync("myapp://com.companyname.myapp1");
    }
}
```

Comment: Already tried it but the result is false..

Comment: then that url scheme is not registered

Comment: Are you testing the application on a simulator or on a physical device?

Comment: I tried on both simulator and physical device.