# Unable to find explicit activity class when open deeplink

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, deep-linking

I had Xamarin.Android App with deeplinks on API32. After I updated API to 33, Deeplinks has broken. I had this exception in my logs:

```
Time    Device Name Type    PID Tag Message
02-14 08:25:48.878  OnePlus IN2015  Error   16453   AcceptInvitation    android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {PACKAGENAME/crc645ff435851f1c2612.MainActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml, or does your intent not match its declared <intent-filter>?
    at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:2184)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1831)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:5555)
    at hcm.platform_startActivityForResult(:com.google.android.gms@230413045@23.04.13 (190408-505809224):2)
    at hcl.startActivityForResult(:com.google.android.gms@230413045@23.04.13 (190408-505809224):2)
    at com.google.android.chimera.android.Activity.startActivityForResult(:com.google.android.gms@230413045@23.04.13 (190408-505809224):2)
    at hgx.startActivityForResult(:com.google.android.gms@230413045@23.04.13 (190408-505809224):2)
    at hcl.public_startActivityForResult(:com.google.android.gms@230413045@23.04.13 (190408-505809224):2)
    at hcm.startActivityForResult(:com.google.android.gms@230413045@23.04.13 (190408-505809224):3)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:5508)
    at hcm.platform_startActivityForResult(:com.google.android.gms@230413045@23.04.13 (190408-505809224):1)
    at hcl.startActivityForResult(:com.google.android.gms@230413045@23.04.13 (190408-505809224):1)
    at com.google.android.chimera.android.Activity.startActivityForResult(:com.google.android.gms@230413045@23.04.13 (190408-505809224):1)
    at hgx.startActivityForResult(:com.google.android.gms@230413045@23.04.13 (190408-505809224):1)
    at hcl.public_startActivityForResult(:com.google.android.gms@230413045@23.04.13 (190408-505809224):1)
    at hcm.startActivityForResult(:com.google.android.gms@230413045@23.04.13 (190408-505809224):1)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:6011)
    at hcm.platform_startActivity(:com.google.android.gms@230413045@23.04.13 (190408-505809224):2)
    at hcl.startActivity(:com.google.android.gms@230413045@23.04.13 (190408-505809224):2)
    at com.google.android.chimera.android.Activity.startActivity(:com.google.android.gms@230413045@23.04.13 (190408-505809224):2)
    at hcl.public_startActivity(:com.google.android.gms@230413045@23.04.13 (190408-505809224):2)
    at hcm.startActivity(:com.google.android.gms@230413045@23.04.13 (190408-505809224):3)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:5978)
    at hcm.platform_startActivity(:com.google.android.gms@230413045@23.04.13 (190408-505809224):1)
    at hcl.startActivity(:com.google.android.gms@230413045@23.04.13 (190408-505809224):1)
    at com.google.android.chimera.android.Activity.startActivity(:com.google.android.gms@230413045@23.04.13 (190408-505809224):1)
    at kmv.x(:com.google.android.gms@230413045@23.04.13 (190408-505809224):4)
    at kmw.onPostExecute(:com.google.android.gms@230413045@23.04.13 (190408-505809224):3)
    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:771)
    at android.os.AsyncTask.-$$Nest$mfinish(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:788)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:240)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:351)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8355)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:584)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1013)
```

I tried to google a solution to this problem, tried a lot:
Changed ProGuard settings,
I checked various variations of calling MainActivity with the name of the assembly and just with a dot,
Updated my libraries and SDK,
I tried to prescribe other activities,
I checked the assemblies work both in debug and in release,
Analyzed dex files.
Nothing really helps.
Own analysis showed that the problem is that there are two MainActivities in
[the list of activities](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qBxoF.png).
I am also attaching AndroidManifest:

```
...
<application android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
                 android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@mipmap/icon"
                 android:largeHeap="true" android:supportsRtl="true"
                 android:label="@string/app_name"
                 android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
                 android:localeConfig="@xml/locales_config"
                 android:name=".MyApplication">
...
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
                <data android:scheme="https" />
                <data android:scheme="http" />
                <data android:host="SITE.com" />
                <data android:host="OWN.LINK" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
...
    </application>
```

MainActivity class has MainLauncher attribute.
Help me please! I spent a day on this and I'm afraid that without help I can be stuck for a long time. Seems like the error might be obvious.

```
[Activity(ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait, NoHistory = true, MainLauncher = true)]
    public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
{
...
}
```

UPD:
Sometimes I had this exception:

```
Time    Device Name Type    PID Tag Message
02-14 08:38:29.150  OnePlus IN2015  Info    28812   MonoDroid   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "PACKAGENAME.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~jXWlqXqgllqjZ1bi2qN5dg==/PACKAGENAME-gqSZGEIemXo6mh-lUysz-w==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~jXWlqXqgllqjZ1bi2qN5dg==/PACKAGENAME-gqSZGEIemXo6mh-lUysz-w==/lib/arm64, /data/app/~~jXWlqXqgllqjZ1bi2qN5dg==/PACKAGENAME-gqSZGEIemXo6mh-lUysz-w==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /system_ext/lib64]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:259)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
    at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(AppComponentFactory.java:95)
    at androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(SourceFile:45)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1347)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3745)
    ... 12 more
```

Comment: Please don´t add error messages as images. Images are welcome if thy clarify the issue. But please post error messages as formatted text in your question.

Comment: @burnsi sorry. Ok I will fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the generated `Manifest.xml` file you posted, I  couldn't find the following `intent-filter`:

```
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
  </intent-filter>
```

so, you can recheck if you have set the `MainLauncher = true` correctly for your Activity.

You can refer to my setting,just as follows:

```
    [Activity(Label = "SearchBarDemos", Icon = "@mipmap/icon", Theme = "@style/MainTheme", MainLauncher = true,Exported =true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)] 
    [
    IntentFilter
    (
        new[] { Android.Content.Intent.ActionView },
        Categories = new[]
            {
                Android.Content.Intent.CategoryDefault,
                Android.Content.Intent.CategoryBrowsable
            },
        DataSchemes = new[] { "myapp" }
    )
]
    public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            LoadApplication(new App());
        }
    }
```

And you can refer to a similar thread here: [Navigate from one app to another using Xamarin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75362752/navigate-from-one-app-to-another-using-xamarin/75369113#75369113).

**Note:**

If you have set ActivityAttribute `MainLauncher = true` for your MainActivity, you don't need to set it on file`Manifest.xml`,which easily leads to generating two `MainActivity`s you said.

On other words,you don't need to add any code into the generating `Manifest.xml` file.

For more information,please  check:[Working with the Android Manifest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/android-manifest).

Comment: Thanx! I am sorry, I forget to say, that I add "MainLauncher = true" To MainActivity. Now I update my post and add MainActivity Code

Comment: Did you add  tag ` <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:exported="true">`  of `AndroidManifest.xml`  manually?  You don't need to add it manually.

Comment: @jessie-zhang-msft Yep. I add this block manually. How I can get it from generator?

Comment: Oh! I am reading your link now. And understand what can I do. I will try to add intent filter to Activity attributes.

Answer (score 0):

The "ActivityNotFoundException" error generally occurs when an Android app is trying to launch an Activity using an Intent, but the specified Activity class cannot be found or does not exist. You can try below some hit and trial methods:

Issue can be because of incorrect activity class name so make sure that the activity class name in your Intent is correct, including the package name.

Also make sure that the activity class must be declared in your AndroidManifest.xml file, or it will not be recognized by the Android system.

If the Activity class is present in your code, but you still encountering this error, it could be because the Activity class is not being included in your APK file. This can happen if the class is not being referenced properly in your code, or if the build process is excluding the class from the APK.

If the Activity class is being launched through a deep link, just make sure that the correct Intent filters are set up for the Activity in your AndroidManifest.xml file.

It's also possible that the update from API 32 to API 33 could have caused changes in the Android framework that are affecting your deep links. You may want to check the Android Developer documentation for any changes in the way that deep links are handled in API 33, and make any necessary updates to your code accordingly.

I hope these findings may help you out to rectify your doubt.

Thanks.